# How is scrolling handled by PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, scroll

How is scrolling implemented by PhoneGap? Is scrolling done by JavaScript plug-in like iScroll, is it done by a native scroll view, or in an other way?

The reason I ask, is because I am new to PhoneGap, and the biggest reason for chossing it is if it handles scrolling in a good way.

Answer (score 2):

Since PhoneGap is a wrapper for deployment, not presentation, scrolling is dependent on the chrome from the browser on the platform you deploy to.  If a device's native browser scrolling is an issue for you (like it sounds like it is on iOS), it will still be an issue in PhoneGap.  Consider using a presentation library, like Sencha Touch, jQMobile or iScroll, to fix the issue on a specific deployment platform.

Answer (score 0):

scrolling in phonegap wont ever come to the level of the native ones..
but iscroll brings it pretty close.